# Adobe AIR multi platform Unique ID (Hardware ID)

Tags: actionscript-3, air

How to get an unchangeable unique ID for make licensing system in new Adobe AIR (ActionScripts3) for multi platform?

If there is no default way in AIR development system, what's best copy protection way for AIR platform?

[I found a good component but this is no longer available.](http://flashvisions.com/goodies/air-android-extensions/device-identification/)

Comment: Google > air device id > first two links. However, what's the point? Sell it via Google Play and let it handle the licensing stuff.

Comment: Do you have a mobile app or a windows standalone ? For windows, you could read the computer's MAC Address. For mobiles it's tricky. You can't read the MAC Address on Android since Android 6.0+. Earlier it was possible to read the IDFA but I believe Apple doesn't allow that anymore (or doesnt allow it if you are not using any ads). But keep in mind all of these would mean the license is only valid for one specific device. What if the user will get a new device? Another way would be to  grant licenses based on an email address

Comment: I'm Unity3D developer, there is a very good API (SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier) that works in all platforms without need to change, It mean is it possible to do this but in actionscripts there is no official solution.

Comment: Email address needs online activation and checking system.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Device Info ane](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-DeviceId) by FreshPlanet.